# ConcurrentModificationException и жизненный цикл активити

Tags: android, activity-life-cycle

Есть приложение, состоящее из активити-контейнера, в котором сменяются 2 фрагмента (список и деталка).
Получаю "RuntimeException Caused by: ConcurrentModificationException" примерно от 0,5 юзеров на 1000. Сам ее отловить не могу.
В приложении есть: moxy, dagger, rx.

C чем это связано?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4179)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1654)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at i.put (i.java:101)
  at fo.a (fo.java:44)
  at fm.onActivityPaused (fm.java:53)
  at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused (Application.java:249)
  at android.app.Activity.onPause (Activity.java:1678)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPause (FragmentActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performPause (Activity.java:7158)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause (Instrumentation.java:1330)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4168)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1654)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Посмотрите статью https://habr.com/post/325426/

Comment: @Евгений Васильев Я не модифицирую коллекцию во время итерирования по ней.